# How can I handle an interface method that may or may not be async?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-runtime, c#-5.0, async-await

I am attempting to create a serialization interface (similar to Cocoa's `NSCoding` protocol) so that I can get a quick binary representation of a class to send across a network or store in a database.  However, some cases (especially involving image encoding) have many async-only methods that require `await`ing.  However, if the bytes do not get written in order then of course the whole representation is corrupted.  I must make sure that the current object is finished serializing before I continue to the next object.  Here is the main loop of what I am doing.

```
 public async static Task<byte[]> Serialize(this IList<ISerializable> list) {
        using (Archiver archiver = new Archiver()) {
            archiver.Write(list.Count);
            foreach (ISerializable value in list) {
                await archiver.Write(value);
            }
            return archiver.Result;
        }
    }
```

`Archiver` just uses `MemoryStream` and `BitmapWriter` under the hood to write either values that `BinaryWriter` can accept directly, or `ISerializable` objects, and then spits out the result as a byte array.  `ISerializable` is just an interface with two methods (`Serialize` and `Deserialize`).  They both return `Task` so that they can be `await`ed.  The problem is when I have a serialization method that doesn't have any async components.  I can do one of two things:

A)  I can tack on `async` to that class's serialization methods anyway and put up with the compiler warning saying that it will execute synchronously (I don't like to have compiler warnings).

B) Manually return an empty task at the end of the method (`return Task.Run(() => {});`).  However, this looks and smells really weird.

Both A and B seem to execute without a problem, but are there any problems with this approach that I may have missed?  I am not aware of a binary serializer in Windows Runtime (I included the tag just to dispel any confusion).  Perhaps there is an option C that I can consider?  Actually I didn't want to make the serialization methods async, but for some reason `task.Wait()` was not waiting, and I was getting a null reference exception from trying to use an object created with `CreateAsync` before it was ready.

**EDIT** I thought of an option C.  I could just wrap the entire method in an `await Task.Run(...)` call.  Would this be normal?

Comment: You could await Task.Delay(0), it returns immediately.

Comment: @HansPassant I rather like that solution ^^

Comment: Is your image processing a third-party library? I ask because it seems to me that image encoding (and serialization in general) are not naturally `async` operations. That said, I prefer @svick's solution, which is like option B with less overhead.

Comment: @StephenCleary No, just regular BitmapEncoder stuff, but all the calls to turn it into streams and stuff are async and I can't find other methods to replace them.  For example, there is no `Stream.Read` equivalent to `stream.ReadAsync` that I find on WinRT and the only way to make a `BitmapEncoder` class is through its `CreateAsync` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best solution here, assuming you want to execute the method synchronously is to write it normally, except you will return a completed `Task` at the end of the method.

To get a completed `Task` with some specific value, you can use [`Task.FromResult()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194922.aspx).

If you want a `Task` with no value (i.e. actually just `Task`, not `Task<TResult>`), you can use for example `Task.FromResult(true)` (which is a `Task<bool>`) and implicitly cast it to `Task`.

Comment: How does this compare, in your mind, to the suggestion in the comments of `Task.Delay(0)`?

Comment: @borrrden Practically, I don't think there is a difference. Logically, I think `FromResult()` makes better sense, because you want a completed `Task`, not a delay. Also, the synchronous version of that code is `Thread.Sleep(0)`, which has a special meaning. That could be confusing.